# sql select records having count > 1 where at lease one record has value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get all participants that have more than 1 record in the table where at lease one of those records has IsCurrent = 0 and IsActive = 1

This is what I have so far, but it's not working:

```
    SELECT  ParticipantId 
    FROM Contact
    WHERE (IsCurrent = 0 AND IsActive = 1 AND ContactTypeId = 1)
    Group by ParticipantId
    Having COUNT(ParticipantId) > 1
```

This query brings back a record that matches that description, but I need all of the records that match that description, there are more.

Comment: What do you mean by "all of the records that match that description" mean?

Comment: @Andrew If a given participant has 4 rows that meet these criteria, the group by will filter this down to only showing the participant once. He want to list all four records.

Comment: I **think** that is what the OP means, but I'd rather the OP clarify.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [EXISTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx):

```
SELECT  ParticipantId 
FROM    Contact
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Contact c2
            WHERE   c2.ParticipantID = c.ParticipantId
            AND     ContactTypeId = 1
            GROUP BY ParticipantID
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            AND COUNT(CASE WHEN IsCurrent = 0 AND IsActive = 1 THEN 1 END) >= 1
        );
```

Comment: this doesn't work, I need participants that have more than 1 record with contact type = 1 where at least one of those records has iscurrent = 0 and isActive = 1

Comment: ok, thanks.  This worked.  I had to add Then 1 End in the case statement, but that did it.

Comment: Woops, long day. I've corrected the missing end to the case statement.

Answer (score 3):

Use it as a subquery and join to it:

```
select * from 
(
    SELECT  ParticipantId 
    FROM Contact
    WHERE (IsCurrent = 0 AND IsActive = 1 AND ContactTypeId = 1)
    Group by ParticipantId
    Having COUNT(ParticipantId) > 1
) base
inner join Contact c on c.ParticipantId = base.ParticipantID
WHERE (IsCurrent = 0 AND IsActive = 1 AND ContactTypeId = 1)
```

Comment: That is not correct.  If it is in base then by definition it is c.  The > 1 is supposed to have no conditions.

Comment: @Blam The `c` table will contain records for IDs that are not in base, and so base is useful for filtering records from `c`. Additionally, the `base` only includes an ID field. Records in `c` contain additional fields beyond just the ID, and a given ID may show up several times in `c` with different values.

Comment: How is it a filter if it has the same where?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  ParticipantId
from Contact as c
group by
  ParticipantId
having 
  Count(*) > 1
  and
  Sum(Case when IsCurrent = 0 then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
  and
  Sum(Case when IsActive = 1 then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
```

I would first try this

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just remove:

```
AND ContactTypeId = 1
```

which seems to be an idexed column

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT  ParticipantId 
    FROM Contact
   Group by ParticipantId 
  Having Count(*) > 1 
Intersect
  SELECT  ParticipantId 
    FROM Contact
   WHERE IsCurrent = 0 
     AND IsActive = 1 
     AND ContactTypeId = 1
```