# Exists sub-query with a HAVING clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, exists

I'm trying to understand how `EXISTS` work.

The following query is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821598/3002584) answer, and it queries for all `SalesOrderID`s that have more than 1 record in the table, where at lease one of those records has `OrderQty > 1` and `ProductID = 777`:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT  SalesOrderID, OrderQty, ProductID
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderDetail s
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Sales.SalesOrderDetail s2
            WHERE   s.SalesOrderID = s2.SalesOrderID
            GROUP BY SalesOrderID
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            AND COUNT(CASE WHEN OrderQty > 1 AND ProductID = 777 THEN 1 END) >= 1
        );
```

What I don't understand is this: The sub-query returns a single-columned table filled with the value `1` on each row. So the way I understand it, the `WHERE` in the outer query has no real condition to apply, just a bunch of `1`s. Why\How, then, the outer query returns only part of the `Sales.SalesOrderDetail`, and not its entirety?

Comment: Because of the `WHERE` condition in the subquery.  This is called a *correlated subquery*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, is the `GROUP BY` needed? it gives the same result without it.

Comment: @OfirD No, the `GROUP BY` isn't needed. It would only by required if you specified a column from `s2`, that doesn't have an aggregate function applied to it, in the `HAVING` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in EXISTS is that, it only checks if the record from the outer table satisfies the conditions given in the inner query. That's why we specify "1" unlike IN where we need to specify the individual columns (and data is checked for each and every record).

So, it does not return any bunch of 1's and validates it. As the name implies, it checks only for the existence of the record as per the given condition.

Hope this clarifies.

Note : Always use table alias names for the columns to prevent ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

the inner `SELECT 1 ...` will not always return 1.

When inner `WHERE/HAVING` condition is not met you will not get 1 returned. Instead there will be nothing, I mean the SQL Server Management Studio (if I recall correctly) will display NO result at all, not even NULL for the inner `SELECT 1` thus failing the whole outer `WHERE` for that particular row.

Therefore part of your outer query result set will be cut off and the total number of rows returned with `EXITS(...)` will be less then if `EXISTS(...)` was not present.